# Perfect Vacuum Beneath an Object

Tags: classical-mechanics, vacuum

Recently I became interested in how suction cups work by creating a region of space with lower pressure than their surroundings, thus sealing the suction cup to the contact surface. Extrapolating this idea further, does this mean that a cube resting on a perfectly flat surface would be unable to be lifted since by doing so, you would be creating a region with zero pressure? Also, keep in mind that I'm speaking in purely theoretical terms and I understand that no object is perfectly flat and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Even though real objects cannot be perfectly flat, they could be flat enough to stick together pretty well.

Common examples are two pieces of glass or gauge blocks wrung together ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lOOl3VxOtE)). Besides vacuum action, other forces, like molecular attraction (adhesion) may play a significant role.

Comment: Very interesting, the video claimed that the force of attraction persists in a vacuum, so does that mean that the phenomenon is not caused by air pressure though? I saw another video that said it was due to atomic Van der Waals forces

Comment: @AlexS That's right.